# Parts' page numbers greater than 100 are misaligned in my ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, koma-script

**Context:** I have customized the layout of the ToC in my `scrbook` document. It looks great, except for entries related to parts. Indeed, if the pertaining page number is greater than 100, the page number is misaligned horizontally.
This is not due to too long part titles as you can see in the MWE below. I've also make sure to disable protrusion to typeset the ToC.

**Question:** How to right align all page numbers?

[image]

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \KOMAoption{listof}{%
        indented,%
        smallchaptergap,%
    }

    %-- ToC layout --
        \KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}
        \addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}
        \addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\mdseries}

        \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1em plus 1pt, numwidth=1.3em]{default}{part}
        \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt, indent=1.3em, numwidth=1.5em]{default}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
    \tableofcontents
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

%Dummy text below   
    \part{First part}
        \chapter{A first chapter}
            \lipsum[1-42]
        \chapter{A second chapter}
            \lipsum[43-90]
        \chapter{A third chapter}
            \lipsum[91-150]
    \part{Second part}
        \chapter{Another first chapter}
            \lipsum[1-42]
        \chapter{Another second chapter}
            \lipsum[43-90]
        \chapter{Another third chapter}
            \lipsum[91-150]
            \lipsum[80-150]
    \part{Third part}
        \chapter{Still a first chapter}
            \lipsum[1-42]
        \chapter{Still a second chapter}
            \lipsum[43-90]
        \chapter{Still a third chapter}
            \lipsum[91-150]
    \part{Fourth empty part}            
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key variable needing adjustment is `\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{<width of page number field>}`.  Here I set it to `2em`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \KOMAoption{listof}{%
        indented,%
        smallchaptergap,%
    }

    %-- ToC layout --
        \KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}
        \addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}
        \addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\mdseries}

        \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1em plus 1pt, numwidth=1.3em]{default}{part}
        \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt, indent=1.3em, numwidth=1.5em]{default}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
    \tableofcontents
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

%Dummy text below   
    \part{First part}
        \chapter{A first chapter}
            \lipsum[1-42]
        \chapter{A second chapter}
            \lipsum[43-90]
        \chapter{A third chapter}
            \lipsum[91-150]
    \part{Second part}
        \chapter{Another first chapter}
            \lipsum[1-42]
        \chapter{Another second chapter}
            \lipsum[43-90]
        \chapter{Another third chapter}
            \lipsum[91-150]
            \lipsum[80-150]
    \part{Third part}
        \chapter{Still a first chapter}
            \lipsum[1-42]
        \chapter{Still a second chapter}
            \lipsum[43-90]
        \chapter{Still a third chapter}
            \lipsum[91-150]
    \part{Fourth empty part}            
\end{document}
```

[image]

I learned this fact from a figure in the documentation to the `tocloft` package, https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft, shown on page 3:

[image]

Comment: You also need to increase "numwidth" for the parts, since the roman numeral for the "IV." is crashing into the following text -  and "VII" and "VIII" will be even worse, if you have that many parts!